# 404 error and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am facing error 404 with my script.

I want to hide the page title.  For example

`http://example.com/final/admin/admin.php`

I want to hide `admin.php`  to be

`http://example.com/final/admin`

Here is my .htaccess that always returns a **404 page not found**  error

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/final/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /final/$1 [L]
```

Here is my index.php code

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Mina Wilson
 * @copyright 2012
 * // EPCI Pharma Survey | Rights Reserved
 */
// Inialize session
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['message']; unset($_SESSION['message']);


ob_start();

session_destroy();

// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page

ob_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {

header('Location: login_process.php');
}

ob_flush();
?>
-- html here
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use rewriterule like this. You can use rewriterule alone

```
RewriteRule final/(.*)$  index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

But this redirects any page after final word to index.php

Comment: Why are you using ob_start()? After destroying session you are checking if (isset($_SESSION['name'])), then how it will work?

Comment: I think it would be better if you remove all codes and place only the below code. <?php session_start(); if isset($_SESSION['name'])){
header('Location: login_process.php');
}